# CCCrypt decrypting in AES

Tags: ios, aes, commoncrypto

In my iOS app I have to decrypt data coming from a server. I use `CommonCrypto` framework and, after several trials, I successfully decrypted with

```
CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, // operation
                     kCCAlgorithmAES128, // Algorithm
                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCModeCBC, // options
                     key.bytes, // key
                     key.length, // keylength
                     nil,// iv
                     cipherData.bytes, // dataIn
                     cipherData.length, // dataInLength,
                     decryptedData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                     decryptedData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                     &outLength); // dataOutMoved
```

In the java server the data is crypted with

```
byte[] buff = new byte[100];
byte[] buf2 = new byte[32];
byte[] mainKey = ...
byte[] raw = ...
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new AESEngine());
KeyParameter par = new KeyParameter(mainKey);
int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
int length1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
int length2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, length1);
int actualLength = length1 + length2;
byte[] result = new byte[actualLength];
System.arraycopy(outBuf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
```

Now, I don't understand the sense of `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCModeCBC`. `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding = 0x0001` and `kCCModeCBC = 2` so `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCModeCBC = 3` but not exist options for block ciphers with value `3`.

Is there someone that can help me to understand?

Comment: *"but not exist options for block ciphers with value 3"* - What do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry @ArtjomB., but as pointed out to me Rob, I misunderstood the meaning of bit fields. now it's more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `kCCModeCBC` here is incorrect. All `CCOption` enum values begin with `kCCOption`. `kCCModeCBC` is part of the `CCMode` enum. You can't combine them this way. You're getting away with it because CBC happens to be the default. You should remove `| kCCModeCBC`. (`CCMode` is used by a newer interface called `CCCryptorCreateWithMode`. The interface you're using defaults to CBC and has an option to switch to ECB mode instead.))

To your deeper question, these are [bit fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). So "bit zero" (which has a value of 1) is PKCS7 padding. Bit one (which has a value of 2) turns on ECB (not CBC). If you "or" them (which this the same as adding them), you get 3, which means both options. This is an extremely common way to pass boolean data in C, giving each field one bit in a larger integer.

If there were more fields, they would have values 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. All powers of two. So the options you turn on or off are exactly a binary number of ones (on) and zeros (off).

C does not have a really good way to maintain type safety for these kinds of values, so it won't stop you from combining unrelated enums like you've done here.

---

The reason it "works" with `kCCModeCBC` is that it has the same value as `kCCOptionECBMode`. Your encryption is in ECB mode, not CBC mode. (Which happens to mean that your cypher is almost certainly deeply insecure, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: If I remove | kCCModeCBC the decrypted result is incorrect. The only way I found to obtain a correct result is kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCModeCBC. I agree with you that it makes no sense. This why I asked this question.

Comment: `kCCModeCBC` and `kCCOptionECBMode` happen to have the same value.

Comment: Ok. So `kCCOptionECBMode` and `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` are not mutually exclusive? If I use only `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` I have a padded CBC cipher. If I use `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode` I have a padded ECB cipher. Right?

Comment: Correct. You can join options together with |.